# How to turn host memory into page-locked using CUDA driver API

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

How can I turn an already allocated host memory buffer into a page-locked memory using the CUDA driver API? Is there any equivalent procedure to achieve the same behaviour of the CUDA runtime cudaHostRegister?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cuMemHostRegister](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1gf0a9fe11544326dabd743b7aa6b54223) is what you are looking for. It is what [cudaHostRegister](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c) calls under the hood to perform the same operation.